# Programmatically defining schema not working for nulls

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, null, error-000622

I am attempting to create a table with appropriate schema. I have created a data dictionary with the appropriate values stored in a list. See below

```
schema_dict = {"borough" : ["borough","TEXT","","",2,"borough","NON-NULLABLE"],
"block" : ["block","LONG",10,"","","block","NON-NULLABLE"],
"lot" : ["lot","SHORT",5,"","","lot","NON-NULLABLE"],
"cd" : ["cd","SHORT",5,"","","cd","NULLABLE"]}
```

Then I use this data dictionary to call the appropriate parameter value when looping through a list of my fields as such:

```
for item in schema_dict:
    arcpy.AddField_management(table_name, schema_dict[item][0],
                                          schema_dict[item][1],
                                          schema_dict[item][2],
                                          schema_dict[item][3],
                                          schema_dict[item][4],
                                          schema_dict[item][5],
                                          schema_dict[item][6])
    print("Converting to appropriate schema for field " + str(schema_dict[item[0]]))
```

For whatever reason I am receiving the following errors:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Add Field). Parameters
>   are not valid.
>
> ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of NULLABLE | NON_NULLABLE.

According to the examples provided in the [add field management doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm), a string of "NULLABLE" or "NON-NULLABLE" should be sufficient, no? I notice the type is Boolean, should I be giving the parameter a value of True or False rather than the strings I supplied?

Comment: integer fields are not nullable

Comment: If you add a print line before passing this, what do you get?  And when running the addfield_management, do any of the fields get added?

Comment: Appears to be an error in [Esri's documentation / code sample](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm#C_GUID-8BCD0CDA-41ED-4A98-A902-E92749FD1841) in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the [documentation for AddField_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm) is incorrect? Using strings "NON-NULLABLE" and "NULLABLE" would throw the following errors

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Add Field). Parameters are not valid.
>
> ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of NULLABLE | NON_NULLABLE.

But switching all my "NULLABLE" values to True and "NON-NULLABLE" values to False (i.e. using Booleans instead of Strings) ultimately gave my output table/feature class the correct schema.

This is counter to the examples provided in the documentation and should be noted for anyone experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine, the text is fine, but you cannot create a nullable integer field in arc when using SHAPEFILES

If you use the tools in arc, or the python window in arc, it will let you include the NULLABLE/NON-NULLABLE parameter but it will not honor it for integer or float fields in SHAPEFILES

**EDIT:**

I figured out why I could not null my newly created "nullable" fields.  I was testing this on a shapefile.  When using a shapefile, integer and float fields will not be nullable even when created with the nullable parameter set to True.
However, it will create nullable float and integer fields in a file gdb.

I created the same field to a shapefile and a gdb using this code:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"test","SHORT","#","#","#","#",True)
```

Here is the result (SHP|GDB):

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't make an INT field Nullable? I just did it in both the UI and through the AddField tool.

Comment: Now try to null the field.  Or just right click on the field and view it's properties.  I guarantee that it is non-nullable.  If you use the tools in arc, or the python window in arc, it will let you include the NULLABLE/NON-NULLABLE parameter but it will not honor it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. Adding boolean parameter values rather than strings gave me the appropriate output. See my answer above.

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst The code will execute, and the field will be added, but it WILL NOT BE NULLABLE.  Test it.

Comment: I have. The fields I marked as true came back nullable. The ones I marked false came back non-nullable. I'm creating the FC in a rather roundabout way, but it did work. I'll share the full code if you'd like to see it

Comment: @jbalk I don’t know what’s going on for you, but making null fields works fine for me.

Comment: @KHibma I figured out why I could not null my newly created "nullable" fields. I was testing this on a shapefile. When using a shapefile, integer and float fields will not be nullable even when created with the nullable parameter set to True. However, it will create nullable float and integer fields in a file gdb.

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst I figured out what was going on. When testing this on a shapefile the fields will not be nullable.  In a gdb, they are nullable.  Thank you for testing and letting me know I was wrong.